# How to pass (or share) observable data (flow) between activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to fetch videos to be loaded inside PlayerActivity.

Since the fetch could possibly take a long time to finish, I need to use a shared usecase (??) so the user can have the option to go to the next activity, if ever a single video has been fetched already, without waiting for the the other videos to be fetched.

While the user is in the PlayerActivity, I'm wondering if the function called in HomeActivity will be cancelled and I will have to recall the fetch function again (which is costly).

This is the only implementation I could think of. Sample:

```
class MyVM @Inject constructor(
    val usecase: SampleUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    
    fun fetchBackgroundTask() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            usecase.loadLinks()
        }
    }
}

class HomeActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    val viewModel: MyVM by viewModels()
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        // ...
        
        viewModel.fetchBackgroundTask()
        
        setContent {
            Button(onClick = {
                startActivity(
                    // ... PlayerActivity
                )
            })
        }
    }
}

class PlayerActivity : ComponentActivity() {
 // Fetch all the loaded links here
}
```

I also thought about using Service but isnt that too much just for this simple use case?

If there are other better workarounds than this, pls do tell!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer#in-memory-cache

Answer (score 1):

As you need your data across multiple Activities, you need a singleton manager class to store global data.

Try with the Singleton pattern or `@Singleton` Hilt injection if you are using it in your project. I will skip this part for your own research.

Your singleton class will have a load method and of course, it needs to use `GlobalScope`

-----------**UPDATED**-----------

`CoroutineScope` is enough, no need to use `GlobalScope`

```
private val _taskResult = MutableLiveData<Data>()
val taskResult: LiveData<Data>
    get() = _taskResult

fun fetchBackgroundTask() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // Load your data
        _taskResult.postValue(result)
    }
}
```

Access this singleton class from anywhere, in this case, it will be your 2 `ViewModels`, pass the result `LiveData` back to your 2 `Activity` and they both receive the same data

Comment: may I ask why it needs to use GlobalScope rather than like: `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: I read again. Yeah I think `CoroutineScope` is enough, `GlobalScope` is dangerous to be used